# Using group by with an array in oracle

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to get an array column while using GROUP BY command?
I am trying to get geometry from oracle database as array of coordinates, but get an error when try to use command GROUP BY

```
SELECT A.C_ID, 
       A.ID,
       COUNT(T.Text),
       LISTAGG(T.TEXT, '/// ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) text, 
       P.GEOMETRY.sdo_ordinates p_geom
FROM G_P_THEME A 
LEFT JOIN G_POLYGON P on P.C_ID=A.C_ID and P.ID=A.ID 
LEFT JOIN  G_P_TEXT T on P.C_ID=T.C_ID and P.ID=T.ID 
WHERE (A.THEME_ID=440 OR A.THEME_ID=47) 
Group by A.C_ID, A.ID
Having (COUNT(T.Text) > 1);
```

it returns an error

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I know that this is because there is no reference to P.GEOMETRY in GROUP BY command if I add P.GEOMETRY.sdo_ordinates in GROUP BY, result will be

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 32
```

and if there is only P_GEOMETRY in GROUP BY

```
ORA-22901: cannot compare VARRAY or LOB attributes of an object type
22901. 00000 -  "cannot compare VARRAY or LOB attributes of an object type"
*Cause:    Comparison of VARRAY or LOB attributes of an object type
           was attempted in the absence of a MAP or ORDER method.
*Action:   Define a MAP or ORDER method for the object type.
Error at Line: 6 Column: 32
```

There is probably something that is needed to use in in SELECT to avoid using it in GROUP BY, but couldn't figure out what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for this can be found at [link](https://community.oracle.com/message/14322604#14322604). Reading from the database is much faster than with the solution that [Balazs Papp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/28019/balazs-papp) suggested.

Just to mention in Balazs answer "fetch first 1 row only" need to be changed with ROWNUM=1 in older versions.

Comment: This answer is not useful. It links to Oracle community, but you have to have some level of permission to see it I don't have.

Answer (score 4):

[Restrictions on the GROUP BY Clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/SELECT.htm#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2078943)

> This clause is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - **You cannot specify LOB columns, nested tables, or varrays as part of
>     expr.**
> - The expressions can be of any form except scalar subquery expressions.
> - If the group_by_clause references any object type columns, then the
>     query will not be parallelized.

So here comes a cheap and dirty workaround, and no, I do not recommend using this in production.

```
drop table t1 purge;
create table t1(c1 SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY);
insert into t1 values(SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 1));
insert into t1 values(SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 1));
insert into t1 values(SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 2));
commit;

SQL> select c1 from t1;

C1
------------------------
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 1)
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 1)
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 2)
```

This obviously fails:

```
select c1, count(*) from t1 group by c1;
select c1, count(*) from t1 group by c1
                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY
```

But this works:

```
select ora_hash(c1), count(*) from t1 group by ora_hash(c1);

ORA_HASH(C1)   COUNT(*)
------------ ----------
   111675277          1
   390137838          2
```

Using this:

```
select
  (
    select c1 from t1
    where ora_hash(c1) = group_by_sq.ora_hash_c1
    fetch first 1 row only
  ) as c1,
  group_by_sq.t1_count
from
(
  select ora_hash(c1) as ora_hash_c1, count(*) as t1_count
  from t1  group by ora_hash(c1) 
) group_by_sq
;

C1                               T1_COUNT
------------------------------ ----------
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 2)                1
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 1)                2
```